# Chat in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, chat

I have my existing java web application running production (maven java project). Now I want to embed a chat in my application on screen right bottom. How should I go about it? Is there any easy way, sample or API which I can just add the chat application? My web application only can be used for logged in users so I want to have all the user who are logged in my application to chat with each other 1 to 1 or in a chat group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample chat code in javascript using https://www.applozic.com Chat library:

https://jsfiddle.net/devashishmamgain/amjvszpp/

Javascript:

```
   (function(d, m){var s, h;
   s = document.createElement("script");
   s.type = "text/javascript";
   s.async=true;
   s.src="https://apps.applozic.com/sidebox.app";
   h=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   h.appendChild(s);
   window.applozic=m;
   m.init=function(t){m._globals=t;}})(document, window.applozic || {});

     window.applozic.init({
    appId: 'applozic-sample-app',      //Get your application key from https://www.applozic.com
    userId: 'jsfiddle',                     //Logged in user's id, a unique identifier for user
    userName: 'JSFiddler',                 //User's display name
    imageLink : '',                     //User's profile picture url
    email : '',
    contactNumber: '',
    desktopNotification: true,
    notificationIconLink: 'https://www.applozic.com/favicon.ico',    //Icon to show in desktop notification
    onInit : function(response) {
       if (response === "success") {
          // login successful, perform your actions if any, for example: load contacts, getting unread message count, etc
       } else {
          // error in user login/register (you can hide chat button or refresh page)
       }
   },
   contactDisplayName: function(otherUserId) {
         //return the display name of the user from your application code based on userId.
         return "";
   },
   contactDisplayImage: function(otherUserId) {
         //return the display image url of the user from your application code based on userId.
         return "";
   }
  });
```

HTML:

```
Open this fiddle in another tab and put userId: "jsfiddle2" in javascritp section and data-mck-id="jsfiddle1" in html a hyperlink below

<br><br>
<a href="#" class="applozic-launcher" data-mck-id="jsfiddle2" data-mck-name="JSFiddler 2">Click to CHAT</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="applozic-launcher" data-mck-id="applozic" data-mck-name="Applozic">Chat with Applozic</a>
<br>
Applozic Chat and Messaging SDK to bring real time chat to your mobile apps and websites in just few lines of code.
<br>
Visit <a href="https://www.applozic.com">Applozic</a> to know more.
```

More sample codes are available at: https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin/

Disclaimer: I am the Cofounder @Applozic